# Test database not empty after running ./manage test --keepdb

Tags: django, django-testing

Here is a minimal example of a test I'm trying to run

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import TestCase

User = get_user_model()

class UserTests(TestCase):
    # def tearDown(self):
    #     User.objects.all().delete()

    def test_user(self):
        User.objects.create(username='testuser')
```

The first time it runs fine. But the second time it produces

```
...lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'testuser' for key 'username'")
```

The entry from the previous run is still in the database, hence the duplicate entry error. I thought using `django.test.TestCase` (as opposed to `unittest.TestCase`) clears the test database every time it is run? The problem disappears if I uncomment the `tearDown` function. In the end, it's not a big effort to include all the models in `tearDown`, but still, I wonder why this is necessary.

Here are my database settings:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'materials',
        'USER': config('DB_USER', default=''),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD', default=''),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

The storage engine is Aria.

Comment: In the question title, you stated that you ran with `--keepdb`... is that true?

Comment: Correct, I didn't want to wait for the migrations to run every time.

Comment: oops.  That was a red herring.  Note that django TestCase can only rollback test data when run on a database that supports transactions.  I am not familiar with Aria, but from a quick web search it is not clear at all to me whether it supports transactions in a way that django can make use of.  I'm guessing that's probably the issue.

Comment: That's what I suspected and that turned out to be the reason. After switching to InnoDB the problem disappears.